# Yii2 isGuest giving exception in console application

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In console application when I used `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` it is giving the below exception:

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting unknown prop
erty: yii\console\Application::user'
```

I even tried adding the user in components array in config file. But it didn't worked. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, post your config file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Console application `Yii->$app->user` does not exist. So, you need to configure `user` component in `config\console.php`.

like as,

**config\console.php**

```
 'components' => [
 .........
 ......
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            //'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'session' => [ // for use session in console application
            'class' => 'yii\web\Session'
        ],
 .......
]
```

To check it works or not using below code.

```
public function actionIndex($message = 'hello world')
{
    echo $message . "\n";
    $session = \Yii::$app->session->set('name', 'ASG');

    if(\Yii::$app->session) // to check session works or not
        echo \Yii::$app->session->get('name')."\n";

    print_R(\Yii::$app->user);
}
```

More info about your problem : [Link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5434)

**Note :**  There's no session in console.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple. [Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-application-components.html#core-application-components) says about application components (user is a component):

> user: represents the user authentication information. This component
>   is only available in Web applications Please refer to the
>   Authentication section for more details.

So `Yii::$app->user` it not available in console applications.

As a consequence you have to consider using this component in model classes that are also used by console applications.

Extra note: it is internally used by [BlameableBehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-blameablebehavior.html), however, this makes no problems since user will be null if a model gets saved/created and no user is available.