# Yii2 - Getting unknown property: yii\console\Application::user

Tags: php, yii, yii2, console-application, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to run a console controller from the terminal, but i am getting this errors every time

```
Error: Getting unknown property: yii\console\Application::user
```

here is the controller

```
class TestController extends \yii\console\Controller {

public function actionIndex() {
    echo 'this is console action';
} }
```

and this is the concole config

```
return [
'id' => 'app-console',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
'modules' => [],
'components' => [
    'log' => [
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
'params' => $params];
```

I tried running it using these commands with no luck

```
php yii test/index
php yii test
php ./yii test
```

can anyone help please?

Comment: Once you are using "test" and sometimes "text". Might that be the problem?

Comment: `TestController` you should use `php yii test/index` And show full stacktrace of error.

Comment: No actually its just a question typo, it is test

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Console application does not have `Yii->$app->user`. So, you need to configure `user` component in `config\console.php`.

like as,

**config\console.php**

```
 'components' => [
 .........
 ......
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            //'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'session' => [ // for use session in console application
            'class' => 'yii\web\Session'
        ],
 .......
]
```

More info about your problem see this : [Link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5434)

OR

Visit following link :
[Yii2 isGuest giving exception in console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036766/yii2-isguest-giving-exception-in-console-application)

**Note :**  There's no session in console application.

Comment: well, thanks it solved the user error but now am getting the session error yii\console\Application::getSession(), i tried to remove it since there is no sessions in console but still getting the same error. any ideas?

Comment: would you check following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036766/yii2-isguest-giving-exception-in-console-application) ?

Comment: Actually i did, i have the same config but still the session error appears

Comment: you want to remove session in console? if yes so, just remove `session` component from `components` array.

Comment: well, i don't need the session in console, i tried to remove it from config but still getting the same error.

Comment: You need to clear cache or runtime asset of application.

Comment: do you have any link that explain this process, i googled it but it seems that i have to delete the run time files.

Comment: just delete all folders from runtime folder and also delete asset's inner folder.

Comment: Did this solution ever work? I have a console script that is throwing the same yii\console\Application::getSession() error and deleting the contents of the runtime directory hasn't fixed it.

Comment: I found the answer. See kurmi's response below for the rest of the fix.

Answer (score 6):

Set in \console\config\main.php

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'user' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\Credential',// class that implements IdentityInterface
        //'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

now in your \console\controller\AbcController.php add init method

```
 public function init() {
        parent::init();
        Yii::$app->user->setIdentity(Credential::findOne(['id'=><cronloginid>]));
    }
```

create a cron login and pass that login id in  variable with this config your Blameable Behavior of yii2 will work

Comment: A little out of date, but worked perfectly! I'm writing a console command that imports data into the application and I wanted to use the models that already exist to do my validations and inserts, but these models need to know what user account is performing actions. I needed to simulate a "sessionless" login in the console so all models had scope of Yii::$app->user->identity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @GAMITG said, you must config user component in config file, but unfortunately, you couldn't access session in console, that's because session is not available in console. Maybe you could solve the problem like this:

```
$user_id = isset(Yii::$app->user->id) ? Yii::$app->user->id : 0;
```