# Yii Console Script, Login to User

Tags: php, yii2

I'm working on a console controller that imports data into a Yii2 app. I'm attempting to use the app's existing models for this import instead of re-engineering all of my validations and inserts, but many of the models use ::beforeSave method to give ownership of newly created records to the user who is logged in. I've been told to apply record ownership to the admin user, but I'm not certain how to "login" a user from a console controller as the Yii::$app->user property appears to not exist in console controllers.

How do I populate the Yii::$app->user->identity property with a user account of my choice for the duration of a console controller's actions?

```
<?php

namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;
use Yii;

class TestController extends Controller
{
  public function beforeAction($action)
  {
    // Set the user identity to admin
    $user = $model->find()->where(['usr_username' => 'admin'])->one();
    Yii::$app->user->login( $user );
  }
  
  public function actionRun()
  {
    /*
    Yii::$app->user->identity
    ...should reflect the admin account set above so any controllers or models I invoke see this user performing actions
    */
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to configure the user component for the console app , i cant add code at the moment you can see this post for defining the user component in the console app inside the console/config.php file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174750/yii2-getting-unknown-property-yii-console-applicationuser

Comment: It sort of worked. It's throwing 'yii\base\UnknownMethodException' with message 'Calling unknown method: yii\console\Application::getSession()' now and now I have a new error to work through.

Comment: Kurmi's response to this thread worked for me. It was a little out of date since I don't have a /console/config/main.php file. Instead, I have /config/console.php. But the same modifications to the config and controller produced the result I expected.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37234737/676923